# Simulating the string split function

Tags: c#, function, split, visual-c#-express-2010

I have created a split function: every word in sentence is added as an element in a `string` array.

I'm having a problem with the last word; it's not being added to the output array:

**The code:**

```
// the funcion
static void splits(string str)
{
   int i=0;
   int count=0;
   string[] sent = new string[2];
   string buff= "";
   while (i < str.Length)
   {
      if (str[i] == ' ')
      {
         sent[count] = buff;
         count++;
         buff = "";
      }
      buff += str[i];
      i++;
   }
     Console.WriteLine(sent[0]);
}
```

---

```
// When used
splits("Hello world!");
```

### -----------------------------------------------

---

**I found the solution and It is very simple

I hope everyone will benefit**

```
static void splits(string str)
{
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  string[] sent = new string[2];
  string buff = "";
  str += " ";         // the solution here, add space after last word
  while (i < str.Length)
  {
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
       sent[count] = buff;
       count++;
       buff = "";
    }
    buff += str[i];
    i++;
  }

  for (int z = 0; z < sent.Length; z++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(sent[z].Trim());
  }
}
```

The result will be look like this ([visual result here](http://ideone.com/HbeBR))

```
Hello  
world!
```

Comment: `string[] pieces = "Hello World!".Split(' ');`

Comment: I would love to see performance comparison...

Comment: @Matthew: I know (Split function) in c#, but I want to simulate it

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or is there a purpose behind it?

Comment: @mellamokb: not academic exercise, but I want to create functions without reliance on built-in functions to increase my skill

Comment: Whatever for?  That seems counterproductive :/  It's very unlikely that you are going to come up with an improvement on the built-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

When you have exited the `while` loop, you need to manually add the remaining characters as the final entry in the array.  This is because you split on the character  (space), but there is no space following the final word to signal a word to add:

```
...
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buff))
    sent[count++] = buff;
```

Sample: http://ideone.com/81Aw1

---

However, as `@Matthew` points out, unless you have some special functionality you need to implement, you should just use the built-in split function:

```
"Hello World!".Split(' ');
```

This works out of the box in one line of code and has already been exhaustively tested by the developers of the .NET Framework and countless users.

Comment: Thanks, I know,but I don't want to use the built-in split function, I want to simulate it

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str[i] == ' ')
```

will never fire for the last word

```
while (i < str.Length)
{
   if (str[i] == ' ')
   {
      sent[count] = buff;
      count++;
      buff = "";
   }
   else
   {
       buff += str[i];
   }

   i++;
}
sent[count] = buff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the buffer after you complete your while loop to find out if a last word is still in there. Additionally, you are only printing the first element.

```
// the funcion
static void splits(string str)
{
   int i=0;
   int count=0;
   string[] sent = new string[2];
   string buff= "";
   while (i < str.Length)
   {
      if (str[i] == ' ')
      {
         sent[count] = buff;
         count++;
         buff = "";
      }
      buff += str[i];
      i++;
   }
   if (buff.Length > 0) {
       sent[count] = buff;
       count++;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
       Console.WriteLine(sent[i]);
}
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 spaces in the source string?  This answer, like the OP, only initializes the sent array with 3 indices.  If there are more than 3 spaces, then this will throw an exception.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway True, I didn't notice

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: unfortunately, there is an error and not not work well

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
 private Array SplitSentence(string splitMe)
 {
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(splitMe)) return null;
   var splitResult = splitMe.Split(" ".ToArray());
   return splitResult;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said earlier for all, I don't want to use the built-in split function.   I want to simulate it

Answer (score 0):

To make the solution reusable, I've calculated the number of spaces first; I've also handled the last word as a special case (which as a consequence makes this work with input that contains no spaces). It should be easy to adapt this to work for any delimiter.

```
  string s = "Test spaces in a sentence :)";
  int numSpaces = 1;
  foreach (char c in s)
  {
    if (c == ' ')
    {
      ++numSpaces;
    }
  }
  string[] output = new string[numSpaces];
  int spaceIndex = s.IndexOf(' ');
  int index = 0;
  int startIndex = 0;
  --numSpaces;
  while (index < numSpaces)
  {
    output[index] = s.Substring(startIndex, spaceIndex - startIndex);
    startIndex = spaceIndex + 1;
    spaceIndex = s.IndexOf(' ', startIndex);
    ++index;
  }
  output[index] = s.Substring(startIndex);
  foreach (string str in output)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
```